# Trying to understand how to design properly asynchronous signals in SystemVerilog

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, clock, system-verilog

I have implemented a serial-in parallel-out register implemented in SystemVerilog:

```
module sipo_reg(
    input   wire        in_data,
    output  wire [7:0]  out_data,
    output  wire        rdy,
    input   wire        rst,
    input   wire        clk
);
    reg [7:0] buff;
    reg [2:0] i;
    reg was_enabled;


    always @(posedge clk, posedge rst) begin
        if (rst) begin
            buff <= 0;
            i <= 7;
            was_enabled <= 0;
        end else begin
            was_enabled <= 1;
            buff[i] <= in_data;
            i <= i == 3'd0 ? 3'd7 : (i - 3'd1);
        end
    end

    assign rdy = (i == 3'd7) & was_enabled;
    assign out_data = {8{rdy}} & buff;
endmodule
```

I'm wondering if this is not a very good design because it might happen that  `rdy` goes high before `out_data` has settled, leading to an incorrect read.

For instance, in the following code:

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
  if (rdy)
     my_data <= out_data;
end
```

It could happen that `rdy` reaches the positive edge before `out_data` has settled.

However, given that `rdy` changes some small delay after `(posedge clk)`, one would say that `rdy` is asynchronous with respect to `clk` and can't just be read on the clock edge, since it could not respect the flip-flop setup-and-hold times. It would need to be synchronized to some clock signal, by passing it through two back-to-back flip flops (as explained [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/595824/fpga-spi-slave-doesnt-work-if-driving-it-with-the-fast-fpga-clock-instead-of-wi)). **Is this correct?**:

```
cell_sync cs(clk, rst, rdy, rdy_sync); // rdy_sync synchronized with clk

always @(posedge clk) begin
  if (rdy_sync)
     my_data <= out_data;
end
```

However, in the code above, the problem no longer exists since `rdy_sync` will go high almost two clocks later than `rdy` does. As long as the clock period is slow enough to assure that all combinational logic in the design will have time to settle, `out_data` will necessarily have settled before it is read, **am I right**?

I have tried this on my simulation, and it works, yet I wonder if my reasoning is correct specially when implementing this design in a physical FPGA.

Finally, the most problematic scenario I can think about is:

```
always @(posedge rdy)
   my_ff <= out_data;
```

This already fails in my simulations, so I have replace the last two continuous assignments by:

```
wire _rdy;

assign _rdy = (i == 3'd7) & was_enabled;
assign rdy = ~(~(~(~_rdy)));
assign out_data = {8{_rdy}} & buff;
```

The above works in my simulation, but I'm not very sure about the physical FPGA:

Having that `out_data` only needs 8 *and* gates in parallel, and `rdy` needs 4 *not* gates in series, assuming that the delay of the and and or gates are the same (by and and or gates I mean whatever logic the fpga actually uses to implement then), `out_data` should settle way before `rdy` does. Still, this still looks a bad design to me, because seems unsafe. **Would I be right trying to avoid this solution?** **Can I be sure the synthesizer will not optimize out those not gates?**

In addition, it seems bad to me to do `@(posedge x)`, where `x` is anything other than a clock or a reset signal. **Is this true?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For instance, in the following code:
>
> ```
> always @(posedge clk) begin
>   if (rdy)
>     my_data <= out_data;
> end
> ```

It doesn't matter whether `rdy` or `out_data` arrives at the input to this block first. It only matters that both of them arrive and are stable before the `posedge clk` event occurs.

If there is so much delay uncertainty that either one will be delayed so much that this could not be guaranteed, then the synthesis tool will indicate a timing violation.

> However, given that rdy changes some small delay after (posedge clk), one would say that rdy is asynchronous with respect to clk

You wouldn't say that. `rdy` only changes in response to a clock edge, so it is a synchronous signal.

If one of the signals used to compute `rdy` (in the `assign` statement) originated off-chip, then we would consider it an asynchronous signal, because we'd have no control of the timing of that signal.